# How to prevent Chrome from showing " Not secure" for my website in the URL bar?

Tags: https, web-development, security-certificate, iis, iis8

I have uploaded my website in my IIS using static IP. whenever I access it from local or remote it was showing "not secure".

How do I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: We will need much more information than that before we can answer this. Do you have an SSL certificate?  Are you using https?  What is the site technology? (A CMS?  static HTML? custom PHP?)

Comment: I don't have an SSL certificate(but we can create locally from windows server right?)...but I have changed the HTTP to https and its was using HTML technology.

Comment: @Steve I don't think the site technology matters and they clearly don't have a certificate.  The only question I have is whether or not they have a domain name or they are just trying to access the site by the static IP address.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I don't have a website. I'm accessing by using static IP addresses globally. but when I am accessing the web site it was showing not secure. even I bind the self-signed certificate using my IIS

Comment: As the duplicate question says, you need a trusted HTTPS certificate (not just a self-signed one.)   That means you need to get a domain name.   You can't get a trusted certificate for an IP address.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Where could I buy trusted SSL for a *website which was bound using as static IP*

Comment: You can't. You have to get a domain name first.